# Error while executing make on mydumper

Tags: c++, mysql, c, cmake

I'm trying to install mydumper but the make step complains about undefine symbols. I've searched other questions where they talk about linking your object file to make sure the compiler can find the methods it needs. However this is just plain installation and I am not a C guy. Any pointer is highly appreciated. Here's the error I am seeing:

```
[ 16%] Linking C executable myloader
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFStringGetCString", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
"_CFStringGetCStringPtr", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
"_CFStringGetLength", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
"_CFURLCopyFileSystemPath", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
"_CFURLCreateFromFSRef", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
"_FSFindFolder", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
"std::terminate()", referenced from:
  ___clang_call_terminate in libmysqlclient.a(ssl.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make[2]: *** [myloader] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/myloader.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I think it is because of the similar file `libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o` which isn't supposed to be used to compile this program, instead you need the compiler to use the file named `libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o`  which is at some other location which is a little different from the compiler used file . To run it you must try specifying the location or deactivate the `libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o`  named file at that location.

Comment: I did a search for all .o files but couldn't find libglib file in that(find / -iname "*.o" > test). I also uninstalled pkg-config but still see the same error. So I think you are right that there is a different version of this file somewhere else but I can't seem to find it.